# Как рассчитать координату для добавления элемента в контейнер со скроллом?

Tags: position, html, javascript, dom

Cобственно, вот исходник:

```
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div id="box" style="position:relative; overflow-x: scroll; width: 250px;">
            <img id="img" src="picture.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

т.е. контейнер позиционируется посредине документа, а в боксе - картинка, которая по горизонтали может превышать размер контейнера и соответственно скроллится.

**Задача:** необходимо добавлять элементы-метки на картинку по клику мыши в то место, где произошел клик (с учетом возможного горизонтального скролла картинки). Не могу правильно рассчитать координату для добавления элемента в бокс. Решение нужно на чистом javascript, без фреймворков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю сам себе.

```
var x=event.pageX, y=event.pageY;
var a=document.createElement('div');
    a.className='myblock'; // параметры завел в стилевой файл
    a.style.top=y-2+'px'; // координаты инфоблока буду на 2 пикселя левее-выше щелчка
    a.style.left=x-2-(body.clientWidth-250)/2+parent.scrollLeft+'px'; // учитываем возможную прокрутку картинки относительно контейнера
parent.appendChild(a);
```

Всем спасибо, все свободны.